# Can malware/intrusion attempt via browser, attack other computers on same local network? (Windows) (no shares setup)?

Tags: windows, security, web, malware

Can malware, if running within a plug-in or elsewhere within the browser, or if downloaded and executed, or within a site that attempts intrusion, attack other machines on the local network, even if no local shares are setup?

Examples too, please for Windows?

Comment: Depends on the malware.  But this question is off-topic for SU.  Please check out the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: @techie007 Unless he is asking about browser security..

Comment: @techie007 which I am.

Comment: IMO This isn't really a question that's suited to SU, as it's very vague, and hypothetical without knowing the configuration of the network in question.  We like specific, answerable questions.  But I'll put in a vague answer, just because. ;)

Comment: I always state that I have given a vote for an answer or a question, and the reason why. Who was the coward who downvoted this question? It's already clear that some folk are saying this question may not fit in su's remit but maybe that remit should be extended. If people really dislike this question on SU, I'd be happy to withdraw/delete it - but then we'd also lose the valuable answers already given - and with that the time people took to make them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, malware obtained through any source may proceed to attack other Windows computers on the local network. Even if no shares are set up, these attacks often use the administrative shares which are enabled by default (C$, for example) in professional versions of windows. They may also rely on exploits in entirely different subsystems.

a high-profile example would be downadup/conficker, which after initial connection would attempt brute-forcing of the administrative passwords on other Windows machines on the network.

This is why any computer suspected to be infected should be isolated from the network.

Comment: +1 Accepted because of the modes of attacks and examples and course of action.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some malware you run can attack other machines on the network.

Will it be successful? Depends (on informaiton we don't have).

Examples of malware which attempt to spread? Check [SARC](http://us.norton.com/security_response/threatexplorer/azlisting.jsp) (Symantec AntiVirus Research Center).

Comment: Viruses cannot crawl networks, worms can, Viruses can infect networks but is done by infected files being shared....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus

Comment: +1 for confirming the question (i.e. yes / no = yes) and for examples.

Comment: moab: true enough, I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Once a hacker (or cracker, if you know the difference) takes control of a machine using a client side exploit (via browser vulnerabilities, that is sending you a malicious link that will fingerprint your browser/plugins and launch adequate exploits against them to compromise the system), he will typically try to [escalate privileges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) (get ADMIN access), then pivot around the network. Pivoting involves launching scans and trying to exploit vulnerabilities in neighbor systems in the network. These vulnerabilities can be detected in any service running in the network.

Yes, open shares are often a hacker's favorite but even if all open shares are closed, the attacker can exploit other outdated services in the network.

See this [video demonstration of pivoting after a successfull client side exploit](http://www.securitytube.net/video/1543) using the free open source exploitation framework [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/).

I Hope this helps!